# InvalidOperationException error in Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created on BeginInvoke

Tags: c#, asynchronous, invalidoperationexception, begininvoke, cross-thread

**InvalidOperationException** error in Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created on **BeginInvoke** i am getting an error while throw an **exeception ex** where the ex shown **BeginInvoke** error and can u refer some method.And i getting error in **ex** where throws the error can someone please tell some other method?
I thank in advance!!

```
private void UpdateGrid(DataTable table)
{
if (dataGridView1.InvokeRequired)
{
 UpdateGridThreadHandler handler = UpdateGrid1
dataGridView1.BeginInvoke(handler, table) 
             }
 else
             {
 dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
 
             }
         }
 
 }
 
 //and the Exception i tried and i keeping try as empty
 try
 {
 }
 catch(Exeception ex)
 {
 writelog.writeline(DateTime.Now.ToString()+"-LoadData-"+ex.Message)
>!  }
```

where **ex** indicates the error of Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created

Comment: There's a worker thread somewhere that we can't see.  Don't start it too soon, wait until the form's Load event fires.

Comment: can i get some refer link as example for this